# Boolean operators and which() function in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe, and I'd like to subset by picking out all the rows that conform to a condition on the factor value for `year`:

```
subset_df <- df[ (which(df$year < '1972') || (df$year > '1982')),]
```

My problem is that the line above returns the whole dataframe, `df`.

Forgive me if this is too basic or simple, but I cannot figure out where the flaw lies.

I'm suspecting there is something regarding `||` which I don't understand, or my other theory is that `arr.ind=T` somehow plays a role.  Either that, or the nature of the `which()` function is a little more complicated than I think it is.

If anyone has any insight, I'd greatly appreciate it.  Thanks for your time.

PS:  yes, this works as expected and returns the correct subset; ie, there isn't a flaw in my dataframe:

```
test_df <- df[ (which(df$year < '1972')), ]
```

as does it's counterpart for 1982.

Comment: so you need data for Years less than 1972 and greater than 1982?

Comment: This _nothing_ to do with the `which` function. Had you used the "|" operator instead of "||" you would have excluded all the values between 72 and 82 inclusive. Had you added `!is.na(df$year) &` you would ahve also excluded ones where df$year might have been NA. Please read ?"|" more carefully. "&" you should use the checkmarks for correct answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that from the helpfile you can read (See `?"|"`):

> For |, & and xor a logical or raw vector... and...For ||, && and isTRUE, a length-one logical vector.

Therefore you may want to change your `||` to `|` and I think `which` is not required here.

```
subset_df <- df[ df$year < '1972' | df$year > '1982',]
```

Comment: You're right,  `which` is not required. it's superfluous.

Comment: @Jiber, I'm sorry, I don't understand what a "raw vector" is.  The documentation is a bit confusing.

Comment: @MattO'Brien: `raw` is a data type, like `numeric`, `character`, `integer`, etc.